# PMA bug: Inserting rows in Batch mode

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have noticed PhpMyAdmin 4x error. It doesn't let to add more than 2 rows at a time using Insert interface. 
When you are adding more field-groups to add more rows at a time, the Javascript doesn't work for these groups-fields (does not uncheck NULL input after value inserted) and these fields doesn't save on submit.

Is this error only for me? How can I add batch rows at once?

Thanks!

- Tested with Crome and Opera

Comment: You wrote "4x". Which exact version did you test? 4.0.7 ?

Comment: it was 4.0.5 and 4.0.7 versions

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with 4.0.7 and Chrome 30.0.1599.66 m. Please show us your table's structure.